# What are the recommended disable_functions for Civicrm, if any?

Tags: php

I've seen various security checklists suggesting the use of disable_functions in php.ini, giving a wide variety of functions to disable.

Is this a good practice with Civicrm, and if so, what are the functions that should be disabled?

So far Google hasn't shed any light on this...
Thanks for your thoughts

Civi 4.6.17, Drupal 7.50